# Getting absolute path when trying to get root directory

Tags: python, import, module, path

I'm trying to generate a text file, `video_man.txt` in a different directory. I have the following code block in my `man.py` file.

```
# Generate text file
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
file = open(ROOT_DIR + "/video_man.txt", "w")
file.write(str(p))
file.close()
```

This code block is in a function called `create_table()` that gets called in a different file. The problem is that when I call the `create_table()`, I get the absolute path of where the function is.

```
/home/user.com/src/iform/dvops/build_iform_app/src
```

I just want to get back `/home/user.com/src` so that I can add `/man-release/VideoArtifacts` to the path and generate `video_man.txt`.

I only get the correct path

```
/home/user.com/src
```

when I try printing `ROOT_DIR` outside a function in `man.py`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where is `man.py` located within your directory structure ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included this. It is in `/home/user.com/src/iform/dvops/build_iform_app/src`

Comment: You mean `ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir())`, don't you?

Comment: @martineau No, `os.curdir` is what I meant

Comment: Oops, sorry my mistake — I was thinking of `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd ../` is change directory command which can be used to go back in directory tree.

example:
If you are in `/home/user.com/src/iform/dvops/build_iform_app/src`, then command
`cd ../../../../` will change you current working directory to `/home/user.com/src/`.

In string notation, if `ROOT_DIR` is giving you `/home/user.com/src/iform/dvops/build_iform_app/src`, then `ROOT_DIR/../../../../` should correspond to `/home/user.com/src/`, which you want.

Comment: So I've done `ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir) + "/../../../../" + "video-release/VideoArtifacts"` and `file = open(ROOT_DIR + "/video_man.txt", "w")` but I get a PermissionDenied error. Which I think means that it thinks I am trying to open a directory as a file.

Comment: That means you don't have write permissions for the file ```firmware_manifest.txt```, make sure you are not changing anything you are not supposed to. Change permission of the file by ```chmod +x firmware_manifest.txt``` using root user.

Comment: I don't think I did anything to permissions. I've never used `chmod` to change permissions. I also tried using the command you provided.

Comment: Try ```chmod 777 firmware_manifest.txt```, or else it is not a permission related issue.

Comment: Yeah, must be something else. Thank you for the info though.